# Unable to pull private repo in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-registry

I created an image for my application and uploaded it as `private` repository in `registry.hub.docker`.

Now I every time I try to pull it, I get the following error

```
FATA[0012] Repository not found
```

I have successfully authenticated myself with docker using `docker login` command

Command I ran

```
## docker login
docker login
Username (werain): werain
WARNING: login credentials saved in /Users/werain/.dockercfg.
Login Succeeded

## docker pull
docker pull werain/digitdem
```

Any Clue?

Comment: And you just have a single private repository on the hub? You haven't paid for more? I might give this a try myself.

Comment: I'll get back to you then shortly; I have *no* answer per se right now. What you've done *should* in all likeliness work :)

Comment: Sorry But I'm all out of idea; I actually *do* have a private repository called ``prologic/idd`` that I push/pull to/from all the time as my portable "UNIX as an IDE" image.

Answer (score 0):

Use the full image name, including the tag, when pushing and pulling:

```
docker push werain/digitdem:latest
docker pull werain/digitdem:latest
```

Docker generally assumes you mean `latest` when you don't specify, but if you want to use your own tag or if you didn't push the same tag as you're trying to pull, then omitting the tag won't work.

Comment: Huh? I don't *get* this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Add .netrc file to the dockerfile will pass credentials inside the docker containers and helps to pull more than one private repositories to build dependencies

```
#vim .netrc
  machine github.com
      login < your github token >
```

Add those 2 lines and pass your github token

Then copy the .netrc file to the container by including this line

```
COPY .netrc /root/
```